# Несколько message_handler одного типа в боте на pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Пишу бота для выдачи погоды пользователю с двумя основными командами: `/getp` и `/sets`. Первая выдаёт прогноз по городу, вводимому пользователем вручную или через клавиатуру, вторая открывает список настроек (все имеют два состояния (вкл./выкл.)), изменяемых за счёт отправки критерия настройки пользователем таким же образом, как и в прошлой команде.

Получение сообщения, необходимого для дальнейшей работы, в обоих случаях реализовано через `message_handler(content_types=["text"])`, потому ответ для одной команды, выполненной после отличной от неё, закономерно относится к прошлой команде, что мне не нужно. Реализовать через `register_next_step_handler` не выйдет, так как невозможно предсказать, какую команду далее использует пользователь.

Как разграничить получаемые ответы? Есть ли какой-либо способ остановить `message_handler` после запуска?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сделать булевы переменные в командах. Например, если пользователь ввёл команду `/getp`, то в коде обработчика этой команды присваивать значение `True` переменной `getp_is_called`. Затем проверять её значение в обработчике `message_handler(content_types=["text"])` и выполнять необходимые действия:

```
if getp_is_called:
    [нужный вам код]
    getp_is_called = False
```

И в конце снова возвращать значение `False`.
Так же и со второй командой.